# I need to parse particular json file but stucked

Tags: json, windows, parsing, batch-file

There are json file with variable quantity of elements describing the keywords. The following is the typical example:

```
{"keywords":[{"keyword":"halloween","score":0.9621220167107003},
{"keyword":"pumpkin","score":0.9527655356551675},
{"keyword":"nature","score":0.8530320061364176},
{"keyword":"animal","score":0.7936456829239327}],"status":"ok"}
```

The script should parce this json and I need to get a line with keywords formatted as following:

```
,,,"halloween,pumpkin,nature,animal"
```

As I already stated, the number of entries may be different. From 10 to 100, for example.

Honestly, I am stuck with that task. Would anyone help me please?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set keywords=""

  rem Loop through each line of the keywords.txt file
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims={" %%b in (keywords.txt) do (
    rem Extract the keyword from the current line
    set keyword=%%b
    set keyword=!keyword:"keyword":"!
    set keyword=!keyword:",score":!
    set keyword=!keyword:,!

    rem Add the keyword to the keywords variable
    set keywords=!keywords!,!keyword!
  )
```

But it doesn't help anything

Comment: I've reformatted your sample data. Since you've used a `skip` in your code, it would appear there's a line of data missing else you'd skip the `halloween` line. Are there any other missing lines? (Obfuscate if need be). Do you really want three commas on the report?

Comment: I cannot change the format of input json because it is answer of third party site's API (everypixel.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, that information doesn't tell us what your format actually is. Is it all one line? I can only conclude that it is a number of lines given that you used a `skip` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've included the tag [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing), but as Batch doesn't support JSON at all, I hope you realize that you can't use it to parse JSON without resorting to fragile hacks.

I'd recommend you use a dedicated JSON tool instead, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s "keywords.txt" -e "$json//keyword" --output-separator=,
xidel -s "keywords.txt" -e "join($json//keyword,',')"
```

And if you really want the surrounding double-quotes, either of these will do:

```
xidel -s "keywords.txt" -e "concat('\"',join($json//keyword,','),'\"')"
xidel -s "keywords.txt" -e "'&quot;'||join($json//keyword,',')||'&quot;'"
xidel -s "keywords.txt" -e "x'\"{join($json//keyword,',')}\"'"
```

> *it is answer of third party site's API (everypixel.com)*

If it's simply through a GET- or POST-request (with `curl`?) how you got this JSON in the first place, then `xidel` help out as well. No need to save it to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75438837.txt"

SET "words="
SET "snagnext="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "LINE=%%e"
 FOR %%y IN ({ } [ ] :) DO SET "line=!line:%%y=,!"
 FOR %%y IN (!line!) DO (
  IF DEFINED snagnext SET "words=!words!,%%~y"
  SET "snagnext="
  IF "%%~y"=="keyword" SET "snagnext=Y"
 )
)
SET "words=%words:~1%"
SET words
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Read each line; replace each colon and various brackets with commas. The result is a simple comma-separated list in `line`. Some elements may be quoted.

Use a simple `for` to iterate through all of the elements on each line. If the element stripped of quotes and requoted is `"keyword"` then set the `snagnext` flag to `y`.

The next element to appear when `snagnext` is defined gets accumulated into the `words` list.

Tip: Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Comment: yes  it's magically working =), thank you very much. It seems to be today I finally will set up the automatic keywording, with your precious help.

Comment: It is working as standalone but when I tried to integrate it to my script and failed maybe due to different system to name the variables =(

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON, use the help of PowerShell:

Here's a simple one line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile ',,,"""' + $((Get-Content 'keywords.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).keywords.keyword -join ',') + '"""'& Pause
```

Comment: will be it ok for 300-100 files?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 300-100 files, or how that is relevant to the question content, at this moment, or its submitted time. This is an answer to the question you asked, at the time of its submission. It is based entirely on your example file content, uses your given filename, _(in the current directory)_, and should produce the exact output you showed too. I'm not here to guess what you intended to try to do, post solution, or to provide longstanding support for future modifications. My advice is to try this offered answer with your actual JSON file content, and verify the output.

Answer (score 0):

This simpler method combine several conversion steps in lesser commands, so it is more efficient and run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "keywords="
for /F "delims=," %%a in (keywords.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ("!line:*[=!") do set "keywords=!keywords!,%%~b"
)

echo "!keywords:~1!"
```

- The first `for /F "delims=,"` command eliminates from first comma to end of line, so it just gets `{"keywords":[{"keyword":"halloween"` or `{"keyword":"pumpkin"` in `line` variable.
- The `"!line:*[=!"` part eliminates from beginning of line until first `[`, if any, so it process only the first line giving `{"keyword":"halloween"`; that is, the same value of the rest of lines.
- The `for /F "tokens=2 delims=:"` command over previous replacement get just the keyword value, like `"halloween"` or `"pumpkin"`.
- Finally, the `%%~b` used to add each keyword eliminate the quotes.

Comment: Simpler, perhaps for 'pure' batch file scripting, but it, and the other 'pure' batch file solution, relies on a specific style of content formatting. A valid JSON could all be on one line, for instance, or have multiple array items, objects, and even duplicated key names.

Comment: Of course! We all know, and the OP must be aware of, that Batch file "solutions" on JSON and XML files just stop working if the structure of the file changes even in a small detail...